# Laravel Excel: How can I read Excel file and save in the database with relationship of quiz_id in quiz_information table

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, postman, laravel-excel

I'm planning to import a quiz question and choices using excel but it has relationship to the other table. I need to get the id of the **quiz_information** and create the record using an api. My problem is that when I tried to create the record my plan is to input the id first of the quiz_information and then import the excel file. the quiz_id(id of the quiz_information) the number of records I have on the file should have the same quiz_id.

Sample image of my postman:
[image: sample image of my postman]

This is my controller

```
class QuizImportController extends Controller
{
public function show()
{
    return view('quiz_questions.import');
}
public function store(Request $request){
    $rules=[
        'quiz_id' => 'required',  
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xlx,xls,xlsx'
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json($validator->errors(),400);
    }

   $data = $request->validate([
    'quiz_id' => 'required',  
   ]);
  
    $file = $request->file('file');
    Excel::import(new QuizImport, $file);
    
    $quizQuestions = quizQuestions::create($data);
      
    return response(['message'=>"Quiz successfully imported",
    'error'=>false,
    'error code'=>200,
    'line'=>"line".__LINE__."".basename(__LINE__),
    'file'=>$file],200,[],JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
}
```

This is my QuizImport

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $quizQuestions = quizQuestions::create([
        'question_num' => $row['question_num'],
        'question_content' => $row['question_content'],
        'tagalog_question'=> $row['tagalog_question'],
        ]);

        $quizQuestions->choices()->create([
            'option' => $row['option'],
            'remarks' => $row['remarks'],
            'tagalog_choices'=> $row['tagalog_choices'],
        ]);

    }
}

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'question_content' => 'required|distinct:*.question_content',
    ];
}
}
```

My Excel file has a heading row of question_num,question_content,tagalog_question,option, tagalog_choices, and remarks.

The output should be like this:
[image: The output should be like this]